# Change log file name in logger module globally

Tags: python, logging

I'm using logger module with dictConfig (with a yaml file) for my application logging. However, I would to change the log file name globally by adding a date prefix (ex: logpath: /foo/bar/file_20150523.log).

So each time I start my application a new log file is created.

Is it possible in one way of another to do it inside the yaml file or I need to modify the handler in my application ?

Thanx

Comment: After you load the yaml file, append the current date to the file name, then call `dictConfig`. I have never used `dictConfig` before, so I need some time to learn before I can provide detailed answer.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is simple:

1. Read configuration from a YAML file
2. Locate the name of the log file
3. Append the date stamp to the name part (not the extension part)
4. Call `logging.config.dictConfig` and pass in the modified configuration dictionary

Here is the YAML file I use for this example, **daily_log_file.yaml**:

```
version: 1
loggers:
    default_logger:
        handlers: [consoleHandler, fileHandler]
        level: DEBUG
handlers:
    consoleHandler:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: brief
    fileHandler:
        class: logging.FileHandler
        formatter: brief
        filename: '/tmp/daily_log_file.log'
        level: DEBUG
formatters:
    brief:
        format: '%(levelname)8s %(message)s'
```

Here is the script, **daily_log_file.py**:

```
import datetime
import os
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

def yaml_config(yaml_filename):
    global config_dict
    with open(yaml_filename) as f:
        config_dict = yaml.load(f)

        # Append the date stamp to the file name
        log_filename = config_dict['handlers']['fileHandler']['filename']
        base, extension = os.path.splitext(log_filename)
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        log_filename = '{}{}{}'.format(
            base,
            today.strftime('_%Y%m%d'),
            extension)
        config_dict['handlers']['fileHandler']['filename'] = log_filename

        # Apply the configuration
        logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    yaml_config('daily_log_file.yaml')
    logger = logging.getLogger('default_logger')
    logger.debug('debug message')
    logger.info('info message')
```

## Discussion

- `yaml_config` is where the action is. I first load the configuration dictionary from the YAML file, then patch up the file name
- To patch up the file name, I separate the base file name and extension
- I then get today's date and append the time stamp to the file name, then assign the result back to the configuration dictionary
- Finally, I called `dictConfig` to finish the job